# String de conexao PHP Offline

Tags: php, string, conexão

Estou tentando conectar offline a uma base MySQL, mas não estou conseguindo.

O código está  na minha máquina, já tentei pelo IIS e pelo XAMPP mas sempre que tento conectar, apresenta um erro. Segue a string de conexão que estou usando:

```
$host = ""; //computador onde o servidor de banco de dados esta instalado
$user = ""; //seu usuario para acessar o banco
$pass = ""; //senha do usuario para acessar o banco
$banco = ""; //banco que deseja acessar

$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$conexao)
{
die('Erro: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
echo "Conectou";
}
mysql_select_db($banco);
```

Segue o erro que aparece:

> Erro: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication.
>
> Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password').
>
> This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file.

Alguém sabe  por que isso acontece?

Comment: Patrick, você postou a pergunta em inglês no [pt.so]. Você poderia traduzir? Ou a intenção era postar no [so] (em inglês)?

Comment: Patrick, sua string de conexão está vazia. Por isso retorna esse erro.

Answer (score 2):

Reveja suas informações de conexão.

**Informações padrões para conexão com MySQL**

Host: `localhost` ou `127.0.0.1`

Usuário: `root`

Senha: Senha padrão é em branco mesmo

**Então sua conexão padrão ficaria assim:**

```
$host = "localhost"; //computador onde o servidor de banco de dados esta instalado
$user = "root"; //seu usuario para acessar o banco
$pass = ""; //senha do usuario para acessar o banco
$banco = "test"; //banco que deseja acessar

$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
```

---

### Considerações

1. Considere mudar de `mysql_connect` para `mysqli_connect`
2. Considere utilizar uma classe para gerenciar sua conexão ([ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi/))